# Why does Git still show the old commit message even after a revert?

Tags: git

Why does git history show wrong commit message? We reverted a commit and committed back with different commit message, why does'st the file history still show the old commit message. Both revert and commit were part of the same pull request.

Comment: Commits are permanent and can never be changed. That said, you can write a *new* history, then pull the wool over Git's eyes, as it were, swap in the new history, and pretend the old history was never there. Eventually it will expire. But if you have published it—and a pull request does so—that *old* history is still out there in *other* Git repositories, just waiting to haunt you. You must get all of them to ditch it too (e.g., not accept your pull request)

Answer (score 3):

Git keeps the history of all the changes so if you committed something and then reverted the change in same Pull Request but separate commit, the revert itself is a separate commit and it will be kept in history.

having said that, there are still way to change the history. You can for instance amend you last commit with:

`git commit --amend`

Or you simply can squash last two commits into one:
`git rebase -i HEAD~2` and follow instructions in interactive mode.